# regex change second match in string

Tags: vb.net

***Listbox1 contains following strings:***

[random header] random title [random second header]

[some other random header] some other random title

random title

[random header] random title [random second header] (blahblah) {1234}

[some random header] some random title [some random second header]

**I want to leave the first [.*] and remove the second [.*]**

***I hope to get the following results:***

[random header] random title

[some other random header] some other random title

random title

[random header] random title (blahblah) {1234}

[some random header] some random title

***I couldn't get the desired result with the following code:***

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To Listbox1.Items.Count - 1
Listbox1.Items(i) = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Listbox1.Items(i), "\[.*\].*?(\[.*\])", "")
   Next
```

***Please help me***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve it with regex so I used indexof method.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To listbox1.Items.Count - 1

try
Dim M1 As Integer = listbox1.Items(i).IndexOf("(")
Dim N1 As Integer = listbox1.Items(i).IndexOf("(", M1 + 2)

Dim M2 As Integer = listbox1.Items(i).IndexOf(")")
Dim N2 As Integer = listbox1.Items(i).IndexOf(")", M2 + 2)

Dim bw1 As String = listbox1.Items(i).Substring(N1, N2 - N1 + 1)
listbox1.Items(i) = listbox1.Items(i).ToString.Replace(bw1.ToString, "")
    Catch ex As Exception
            End Try

next
```